Mapbox: Text of the point/circle behind is visible over the point in front
I want to show the points and to write data inside. Problem is that the data (numbers) are shown for the points behind instead of the ones in front.
I would also like for smaller number circles to disappear on zoom lvl xx.
This is my code:
 useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) return;

    mapboxgl.accessToken =
      "pk.eyJ1IjoibHVrYXZpNDQiLCJhIjoiY2xieGlkMDl1MDdhbTNvcm1sbThoa2N3ZSJ9.xRmYD6lKyJrGlwUUrzHZFA";

    mapRef.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainerRef.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10",
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom,
    });

    mapRef.current.on("load", async () => {
      const coordinatesPromises = institutions.map((institution) =>
        getCoordinates(institution.address)
      );
      const coordinates = await Promise.all(coordinatesPromises);
      const geojsonData = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: institutions.map((institution, index) => ({
          type: "Feature",
          properties: {
            institutionName: institution.name,
            site: institution.address,
            employees: institution.employees,
            type: institution.type,
            network: institution.network,
            category: institution.category,
            speciality: institution.speciality,
          },
          geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [coordinates[index]?.lng, coordinates[index]?.lat],
          },
        })),
      };

      mapRef.current.addSource("points", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: geojsonData,
      });

      mapRef.current.addLayer({
        id: "circle",
        type: "circle",
        source: "points",
        paint: {
          "circle-color": "#82c5f1",
          "circle-radius": [
            "interpolate",
            ["linear"],
            ["get", "employees"],
            0,
            5,
            100,
            10,
            200,
            15,
            500,
            20,
            1000,
            25,
            2000,
            30,
          ],
          "circle-stroke-width": 2,
          "circle-stroke-color": "#ffffff",
          "circle-opacity": [
            "interpolate",
            ["linear"],
            ["zoom"],
            0,
            ["case", ["<", ["get", "employees"], 500], 0, 0],
            10,
            ["case", [">", ["get", "employees"], 500], 1, 1],
          ],
        },
        layout: {},
      });

      mapRef.current.addLayer({
        id: "labels",
        type: "symbol",
        source: "points",
        layout: {
          "text-field": ["get", "employees"],
          "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Bold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
          "text-weight": "bold",
          "text-size": 12,
          "text-align": "center",
          "text-anchor": "center",
          "text-justify": "center",
          "text-offset": [0, 0],
          "symbol-z-order": "auto",
          "icon-allow-overlap": false,
          "icon-ignore-placement": false,
          "text-optional": true,
          "symbol-sort-key": ["get", "employees"],
        },
        paint: {
          "text-color": "#ffffff",
        },
      });

      mapRef.current.on("click", "circle", (e: any) => {
        mapRef.current.flyTo({
          center: e.features[0].geometry.coordinates,
          zoom: 15,
          essential: true,
        });
        console.log(e.features[0]);
        setSelectedFeature(e.features[0]);
      });

      mapRef.current.on("mouseenter", "circle", () => {
        mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer";
      });

      mapRef.current.on("mouseleave", "circle", () => {
        mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = "";
      });
    });
  }, [lng, lat, zoom]);

I have tried multiple combinations of properties in layout and nothing led to success.
